# Eclipse: Ignore whitespaces during commit

Tags: eclipse, svn, whitespace, ignore

We use "tigris subversion client" plugin to commit code from eclipse. Somehow my eclipse removes trailing whitespaces, add/removes whitespaces automatically whenever I modify any file.

When doing diff I use option "Ignore whitespace changes" to compare only the actual changes that I did. I thought after I select this option SVN will not commit whitespace changes.

But I found that I am wrong and SVN plugin does commit whitespaces also. It really makes difficult afterwards to find exact change that was being done.

How to configure eclipse to not to add or remove whitespaces automatically?

Answer (score 2):

For Java the actions to run automatically when you save a file are configured in `Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions` (project specific settings can also be set). Remove trailing white space is one of the options you can configure.

Comment: I found that "Save Actions" are disabled because checkbox `"Perform the selected actions on save"` is unchecked. I instead unchecked checkbox `"Remove trailing whitespace"` from `"Preferences -> General -> Editors -> AnyEdit Tools"`. I guess this should resolve some of the issues.